# ArcMap fills up full image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, pdf

I have an issue with ArcMap. In the layout view and data view it shows all buildings normal (it's a bit blurry, but it's only for a study not for presentation), but when I export it, all gaps between the buildings get filled. I don't know what the error could be and first thought it would be in some export setting, but it isn't. I made an EMF and inserted the picture in ArcMap and the EMF was filled in too.

[image: ArcMap filling full layer]

Some more background information:
All files are shapefiles (vector)
When I export just the layer with the building information all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is similar to what I encountered at
[Filled Polygons on Edge of Map using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61117/filled-polygons-on-the-edge-of-a-map-arcmap-10-1).

Try running the "Repair Geometry" tool on your polygon layers, especially the layer that is not the buildigs (2e Daaise buurt).

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of exporting the PDF, the print to PDF option. Also I see you have two layers on the legend. If, by any chance, one of them has a transparency setting, then try removing the transparency and just showing the outline to see if it solves the filling up of gaps.